# Closing spoiler when clicking another spoiler

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem, I would like to create a few spoilers. This has worked so far, but I would like that if a spoiler is open and one clicks on another, the opened again closes.

```
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">Show/hide</button>

<div id="spoiler" style="display:none"> 
  Content
</div> 
<br><br>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display='none'}">Show/hide</button>

<div id="spoiler2" style="display:none"> 
  Content2
</div>
```

Comment: Use a function, Dom Event Listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a common class to all spoilers and on click hide the contents of all the spoilers using the class name and simply show only the one you want to show:

I have created a function for this like so:

```html
<script>
function showSpoiler(spoilerId)
{
  var spoilers = document.getElementsByClassName('spoilers');
  for(var i=0;i<spoilers.length; i++)
  {
    spoilers[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(spoilerId).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="showSpoiler('spoiler');">Show/hide</button>

<div id="spoiler" class="spoilers" style="display:none"> 
  Content
</div> 
<br><br>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="showSpoiler('spoiler2');">Show/hide</button>

<div id="spoiler2" class="spoilers" style="display:none"> 
  Content2
</div>
```

`spoilers` is the common class which needs to be hidden before showing the specific one.

**Remember**

`getElementsByClassName()` gives out an array that is why the for loop is in place.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier for you to start, I'll give you an example made for Event Listener for Radio buttons.

code:

```js
document.getElementById("type_test").addEventListener("click", functio_test);
        document.getElementById("type_test1").addEventListener("click", functio_test);
        function functio_test(){
            var x = document.querySelector('input[name="type_test"]:checked').value;
            //var x = document.forms[0].elements.type_test.value;
            if(x == "ola"){
                 alert("Ola José");
                 document.getElementById('disp_0').style.display = 'block';
                 document.getElementById('disp_1').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if(x == "adeus"){
                 alert("Adeus José");
                 document.getElementById('disp_1').style.display = 'block';
                 document.getElementById('disp_0').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                alert("Continua José");
            }
        }
```

```html
 <div id="select_0">
    <br> <input id = "type_test" type="radio" name="type_test" value="ola"> ola 
    <input id = "type_test1" type="radio" name="type_test" value="adeus"> adeus <br/> <br><br/>
    </div>
    <div id="disp_0" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="ola Jose" ><br><br/>
    </div>
    <div id="disp_1" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="lastname1" value="Adeus Jose" ><br><br/>
    </div>
```

I hope the post helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use classes to accomplish this (`class="spoilers"`)

```html
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="toggleSpoiler('spoiler')"> Show/hide </button>

<div id="spoiler" style="display:none" class="spoilers"> 
  Content
</div> 
<br><br>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="toggleSpoiler('spoiler2')"> Show/hide </button>

<div id="spoiler2" style="display:none" class="spoilers"> 
  Content2
</div>

<script>
  function toggleSpoiler(id) {
    var spoilers = document.getElementsByClassName("spoilers");
    for(var i = 0; i < spoilers.length; i++) {
      if (spoilers[i].id != id) {
        spoilers[i].style.display = "none";
      }      
    }
    
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display=='none') {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display='';
    } else { 
      document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be to create two additional classes and add an additional div to use the parent/child association to determine which spoiler (in relation to the button) needs to be displayed.

Starting off with the classes, let's call them

> .spoiler

and

> .active

The idea is to make the .spoiler class hide and the .active class show, like so:

```
.spoiler {
  display:none;
}
.spoiler.active {
  display:block;
}
```

All spoiler elements would have .spoiler as a class and only the currently active spoiler would have the .active class, now let's create our new div which will bundle the spoilers and their buttons to have a common parent.

```
<div class="spoiler-item">
    <button title="Click to show/hide content">
        Show/Hide
    </button>
    <div class="spoiler">
        Content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler-item">
    <button title="Click to show/hide content">
        Show/Hide
    </button>
    <div class="spoiler">
        Content2
    </div>
</div>
```

Now we can use the relative "spoiler-item" class when a button is pressed to determine which spoiler is related to the button being pressed and also remove the "active" class from all other "spoiler" elements to make sure only one spoiler is shown at a time.

I recommend using jQuery for this, due to time constraints I'm not going to be able to do it in pure JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spoiler-item button').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).parent('.spoiler-item').find('.spoiler').hasClass('active')) { // If the item we've selected is already active
      $(this).parent('.spoiler-item').find('.spoiler').removeClass('active');
      return;
    }
    $('.spoiler.active').removeClass('active'); // Close all open spoilers
    $(this).parent('.spoiler-item').find('.spoiler').addClass('active');    // Open relative spoiler
  });
});
```

See JSFiddle for working answer: https://jsfiddle.net/vvm4xe0m